# How to add a CSS style to a div if image name contains XX using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a specific width to an image's parent div if the image name contains a certain string. Can anyone help?
I want to use something similar to this:

`$(".imageBox img").each(function(){
     if ($(this).attr('src') == "image1.jpg"){
           $(this).parent().css('width', '60px');
     }
})`

But instead of finding the entire image src, I'd like to just determine whether the image name ends with '_60x70.gif'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily do it in a one-liner which is a lot simple, using *ends-with attribute selector*

```
$('.imageBox img[src$="_60x7-.gif"]').parent().css('width', '60px');
// simple!! no need of if condition and each
```

But if you want your current approach, then you could well use regex for it

```
$(".imageBox img").each(function(){
    if (/_60x70\.gif$/.test($(this).attr('src'))){
        $(this).parent().css('width', '60px');
    }
});
```

Comment: @user3453309 please mark it as answer by clicking on the tick so it helps future visitors

Answer (score 0):

One more concise version to achieve the same goal:

```
$('.imageBox:has(img[src$="_60x70.gif"])').width(60);
```